# Nginx rewrite root url

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

Im using an nginx proxy, and am trying to replace the base url with my server url. For example I would like to proxy `www.google.com` through my `localhost:8000`, and replace all base url instances (`www.google.com`) with (`localhost:8000`).

My nginx.conf so far:

```
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

   location / {
    proxy_pass http://www.google.com/;
    rewrite ^/.google.com /localhost:8080 last;
}
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove rewrite directive in 'location /' block. And add break;

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://www.google.com/;
    break;
}
```

Comment: The replaces some of the base urls with my servername. How can I replace all instances of `www.google.com` with my server name (`localhost:8080`). Thanks!

Comment: location / already matches all urls, not quite understand what you mean 'The replaces some of the base urls with my servername'. Did you try example above?

Comment: Yes, I tried the example above, however the links for some urls are `www.google.com/foo`, while others are `www.localhost:8080/foo`. I need all links on the page to direct to `www.localhost:8080/foo`.

Comment: If no other dispatch configuration, it should be fine. Did you restart or reload nginx?